# WINCE Automation Tools, Looking for Learnings from Implementation?

Tags: automated-testing

There are very few tools available for WINCE Automation. We are running apps on devices running WINCE OS. Looking for pointers/learning's from folks who have done WINCE Automation?

- Tools Analysis?
- Pros / Cons of Evaluated Tools?
- Tool Recommendation?

Blogs/Pointers for the same if available? Answers from MS SDET folks from their product testing would also be very useful?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best or the most beautiful solution, but it works.

You can install a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server on the device and then drive a test with a VNC-robot.

- WinCE VNC server: http://www.smartlab.at/mobilevnc/
- T-Plan VNC Robot: http://www.t-plan.com/robot/
- OpenSource version of VNC Robot: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplanrobot/

I think the WinCE development community is small and not many resources and or tools are available, Goodluck with finding a solid solution.

Comment: We already tried with SOTI Pocket controller, VNC based execution. We are looking for more options (Open source tools Primarily, not commercial ones. If MSFT SDETs could share some insights would be useful)